# How can i auto-hide the message "You have been subscribed to our newsletter " after sometime?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, contact-form, ajaxform

The message "You have subscribed to our newsletter" is not auto-hiding itself, i have to refresh the page every time i need to enter a new entry in page and also i want the form area to be blank .[see in the below image i want to hide that subscription message after sometime on its own and email area should also be blank to get a new entry.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8bu5.png)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function doSubscribe() {
    var subscriberEmail = document.getElementById("subscriberEmail").value;
     
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("POST", "subscribe-newsletter.php", true);
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
     
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("subscribe-message").innerHTML = "You have been subscribed to our newsletter.";
           
        }
        
    };

    ajax.send("subscriberEmail=" + subscriberEmail);
    return false;
}
```

what should do so the message autohides itself without refreshing the page and the email area should also be blank.

Answer (score 2):

You need a small change in your `onreadystatechange` function:

**NOW**

```
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("subscribe-message").innerHTML = "You have been subscribed to our newsletter.";
}
```

**MOST BE**

```
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var element = document.getElementById("subscribe-message");
    element.innerHTML = "You have been subscribed to our newsletter.";
    setTimeout(() => {
        element.innerHTML = "";
    }, 3000) // Put your delay in milliseconds ex: 3 seconds is 3000 milliseconds
}
```

The `setTimeout()` method calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds. The function is only executed once.

Comment: i also want to clear that email field after sometime so what should i do for that?

Comment: you must get the email field by `document.getElementById` and set the value attr to empty string: `document.getElementById("email").value = ""` **DON'T forget to define `id="email"` attr for your email field**

Answer (score 1):

You can handle that with setTimeout (this example has 2.5 seconds delay), you can set the innerHTML as an empty string, or hide, or remove from DOM, try this:

```js
let elem = document.getElementById("subscribe-message");

function showMessage(){
    elem.innerHTML = "You have been subscribed to our newsletter.";
    setTimeout(() => {
        elem.innerHTML = '';
        //elem.style.display = 'none'; (hides)
        //elem.remove(); (remove element from DOM)
    }, 2500)
}

showMessage();
```

```html
<p id="subscribe-message"></p>
```

Comment: yeah it works for message ..great.... but i also want email field to be blank for new entry...if you can tell  that it would be great

Comment: to reset your input element try: subscriberEmail.value = "";

Comment: can you tell in code how to do it I'm not getting where to use that.

Comment: just at the top inside of the showMessage() function body, above this: elem.innerHTML = "You have been subscribed to our newsletter.";

Comment: thanks.......... motive achieved..........i appreciate your help..